# How can I limit the length of a text field input in flutter?

Tags: textfield, flutter

The TextField widget doesn't seem to have a "limit" attribute to limit the number of characters that can be typed. How I can enforce that only a certain number of characters can be provided as input in a TextField Widget. I tried looking at the decoration property and potentially setting the limit there somehow but that didn't seem to work either. Is there a different widget I should be using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to add an additional snippet to what RSproute mentioned. The full code is here:

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
String text = ""; // empty string to carry what was there before it 
onChanged
int maxLength = ...
...
new TextField(
    controller: _controller,
    onChange: (String newVal) {
        if(newVal.length <= maxLength){
            text = newVal;
        }else{
            _controller.value = new TextEditingValue(
                text: text,
                selection: new TextSelection(
                    baseOffset: maxLength,
                    extentOffset: maxLength,
                    affinity: TextAffinity.downstream,
                    isDirectional: false
                ),
                composing: new TextRange(
                    start: 0, end: maxLength
                )
            );
            _controller.text = text;
        } 
    }
);
```

Comment: I think you don't have to call  _controller.text = text since _controller.value has already text: text. I had some bugs if I keep this line too.

Comment: cursor focus to be handle

Answer (score 179):

Use **inputFormatters** property

example:

```
TextFormField(
      inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
      ]
    )
```

namespace

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Comment: using `maxLength` will give you length counter and increases the Field height, so this answer would be the accepted one, this one is working fine.

Comment: Thank You, It is working fine to me. I used this to restrict the length of AutocompleteTextField.

Comment: Very easy solution. It works also with TextField(), not only TextFormField().

Answer (score 120):

You can use the `maxLength` property and you can still hide the bottom counter text by setting the `counterText` to empty string.

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 10,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    counterText: ''
  ),
)
```

Comment: maxLength: 10, its increase height of textfield

Comment: In the textfield's ```decoration```, set ```counter: Container()``` to avoid increasing height

Answer (score 62):

`maxLength` property is available in Flutter.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLength.html

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 45,
)
```

Comment: The problem is it does add a counter text at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, there is no option to remove the counter.

Comment: @10101010 use inputFormatters to remove the counter text

Comment: decoration: InputDecoration(counter: SizedBox.shrink())

Comment: Just use `counterText: ""`. It removes the counter and the space it takes up while `counter: SizedBox.shrink()` does not. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259386/996314

Comment: @Rokit you are right man

Answer (score 8):

You can control everything about the Text Field with the TextEditingController. So if you were to pair this information with an onChanged event from the TextField you could perform any logic you like in there. For example:

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
String text = ""; // empty string to carry what was there before it onChanged
int maxLength = ...
...
new TextField(
    controller: _controller,
    onChanged: (String newVal) {
        if(newVal.length <= maxLength){
            text = newVal;
        }else{
            _controller.text = text;
        }

    }
)
```

I am able to control the text field to stay within the guidelines because if it ever goes over it, it will revert to what it was before the last type.

Comment: ....and this is the beauty of flutter. We create our own TextFields and do the exact same

Comment: onChange? I guess it is onChanged. You should add 'd'

Comment: better to use `maxLength: 10`

Answer (score 8):

You can set LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter in input formatters

```
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   inputFormatters: [
     LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(n,), //n is maximum number of characters you want in textfield
   ],
),
```

Answer (score 7):

With th version 1.25 this is even easier. The **maxLengthEnforced** property needs to be set to true. Otherwise the response above will not work.

```
     Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 70,
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      maxLengthEnforced: true,
                      maxLength: 2,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Hours',
                        counterText: '',
                      ),
                      controller: hourField,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do that

**Solution One**

`LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter` Creates a formatter that prevents the insertion of more characters than a limit.

```
      TextField(              
              inputFormatters: [
                new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5), /// here char limit is 5
              ],
                ///....
              )
```

---

**Solution Two:**

```
          TextField(
                  maxLength: 5, /// here char limit is 5
```

If you don't want to show counter text at `TextField` bottom then add empty `counterText` in `InputDecoration`

**Example:**

```
TextField(
              maxLength: 100,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  counterText: '',
                  ///....
```

Comment: Both solutions were already provided, you simply copied them, combined and put it as one in your answer. Come on, bring something new and valuable to the table.

Comment: @iDecode Anyway he does that. You are simply making unneccessary comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code snipped to **limit length** and **hide counter**:

```
TextFormField(
   maxLength: 10,
   buildCounter: (BuildContext context, { int currentLength, int maxLength, bool isFocused }) => null,
);
```

Original answer you can find [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18067#issuecomment-454205459).