# How to make TextField stop receiving input when reached max line?

Tags: flutter

As the title, I've set `maxLines:2`, but when I reached the max line, I can still type.
And `controller.value` has the text that is out of the area.

How to make user can't type when the TextField is filled, or cut the value that is out of the area.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution to my problem. Hope it saves someone's time.
Set `minLines: 1` `maxLines: 2`
`scrollPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

And check the maxScrollExtent when `onChaged`, if it can scroll that means it more than `maxLines`

```
onChanged: (input) async {
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50));

                      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0.0) {
                        controller.text = oldText;
                      } else {
                        oldText = input;
                      }
                    },
```

Comment: downvote? It solved my problem, please mention why this answer is not usefull.

Comment: Thanks, I also solved the problem this way.

Answer (score 2):

**Try maxLength with maxLines**

maxLines property is just for lines, not to restrict the length of text.

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 10, //Any specific length
  maxLines: 2,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    counterText: ''
  ),
)
```

**And you can also use this:**

Use inputFormatters property

```
TextFormField(
      inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
      ]
    )
```

namespace

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

**References**

[How can I limit the size of a text field in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955063/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-a-text-field-in-flutter)

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLength.html

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach because both font size and the TextField's size are dynamic, but thanks for answering