# How to prevent typing after some length in flutter text Field

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, string-length, maxlength

If item Quantity is 3 then user must have to enter 3 serial # (comma Separated). I want to prevent user to type further if the comma separated string length reaches to 3. Also Backspace should also work if he wants to erase some value. Please guide me on this:

[image]

Here is My Code:

```
TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: titleTextColor,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Serial #",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: appBarColor),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: appBarColor),
                      ),
                      //[focusedBorder], displayed when [TextField, InputDecorator.isFocused] is true
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: appBarColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Required';
                      }
                    },
                    controller: serialsController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      if (val.isNotEmpty) {
                        int len = val.split(",").length;
                        if (double.parse(len.toString()) > double.parse(itemListOrderDetail[index].LineQuantity.toString())) {
                          showToast("Stop", FToast().init(context));
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit the length of a text field input in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955063/how-can-i-limit-the-length-of-a-text-field-input-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a good solution is using a mask.
Check this package easy mask
https://pub.dev/packages/easy_mask

So , when you change the qtd number u change the mask too.

Edit.

You can use onChanged prop to control too...

```
onChanged:(val){
     if(val.split(',').length > 3){
       yourController.text = val.substring(0,val.length-1);
     }
   } ,
```

Change the number 3 by your QTD var or controller

Comment: any other solution without any package?

Comment: Yes, have a many methods that can you do. But, I think a little more elegant use a mask. For your users is more simple. But I edit the anwser to put other method

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this on a flutter `TextFormField` by using the property named `inputFormatters`.


You have to create your own class extending the [TextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html) class.

For example:

```dart
class SerialNoFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  SerialNoFormatter({required this.quantity}) : super();

  final int quantity;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.split(',').length > quantity) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}
```